# Verilog bitwise or ("|") monadic

Tags: verilog

I've seen Verilog code where the bitwise or operator ("|") is used monadic. What's the purpose?

For example

```
| address[15:14]==0
```

or

```
|address[15:14]? io_din : ramrd
```

Cann't we omit the "|" in these cases?

Answer (score 8):

In this case it acts as a reduction operator, for example:

```
|4'b1000 => 1'b1 (OR)
&4'b1000 => 1'b0 (AND)
^4'b1000 => 1'b1 (XOR)

|4'b0000 => 1'b0
&4'b1111 => 1'b1
^4'b1111 => 1'b0
```

ORing the entire bus to a 1 bit value, or applying an AND/XOR to the entire bus.

This is referred to as a 'unary' operator as it only take a right hand argument. They are covered in Section 11.4.9 of SystemVerilog IEEE1800-2012.

Answer (score 2):

```
|address[15:14]? io_din : ramrd
```

is the shortcut for writing

```
(address[15] | address[14]) ? io_din : ramrd
```

i.e bitwise ORing of all bits of the bus together to generate a 1bit value.
In this case it will evaluate as HIGH if either(or both) bit 15 OR bit 14 is HIGH.

similarly you can write other bitwise operators

```
&address[15:14]? io_din : ramrd   // ANDing

^address[15:14]? io_din : ramrd   // XORing
```

Comment: Note that `test ? if_true : if_false` is identical in meaning to `|test ? if_true : if_false` - the `|` is redudant when used in a boolean context

Answer (score 1):

In the examples provided, the code with `|` is functionally equivalent to the same coded with the `|` omitted. Three possible reason to have and keep the `|` for the provided code are:

1. It gives guidance to the synthesizer: first OR the `address` bits then compare to 0, instead of comparing each `address` bit to 0 then ANDing the results. It is the same functional result with different gate configurations.
2. It following  a coding style or formatting style requirement.
3. It just read better (visually/structurally appealing) because there is a `|address[15:14]==1` on a near by line of code to `|address[15:14]==0`. (Reminder: `|address[15:14]==1` is **not** the same as `address[15:14]==1`)

Comment: Although `address[15:14] != 0` is probably more readable than `|address[15:14]==1`

Answer (score 0):

On the specific question of whether the '|' can be omitted in these cases:

Whether `|address[15:14]` and `address[15:14]` are identical depends on the context (in general, they aren't, because unknowns are handled differently). Your first example compared to `0`, and it's true that the `|` can be dropped in this particular case, but it wouldn't be true if you compared to anything other than `0`.

Your second example is trickier. The LRM doesn't appear to specify how the first expression in a ternary is evaluated. I know of 2 sims that evaluate it as a reduction-OR, so the `|` can be dropped in those cases. However, if a sim instead evaluates it in the same way as an `if` (ie `if(address[15:14])`) then the `|` is required.

Synthesis is simpler, of course, since the synthesiser doesn't have to worry about unknowns.