# What does |variable mean in verilog?

Tags: verilog, operator-keyword, bitwise-operators

I am wondering what `assign hd_trs_detected = |hd_trs_match;` means in verilog. I am mostly interested in the `|hd_trs_match` part. I know that | means bit wise OR, but not sure how to interpret it without a value before the `|`. Is it an understood '1' or '0'? If it is a '0', what would be the advantage of using `|hd_trs_match` vs. just `hd_trs_match` as `hd_trs_detected` would always be whatever `hd_trs_match is`? Or could it be a bit wise operation of itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verilog bitwise or ("|") monadic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303928/verilog-bitwise-or-monadic)

Answer (score 5):

The `|` is a reduction operator. For a multi-bit signal, it produces an output applying the operand to each bit of the vector.

For example,

```
wire [3:0] in;
wire out;
assign out = |in; // the same as out = in[3] | in[2] | in[1] | in[0];
```

You can do the same with `&`, `^`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

In this ussage the `|` is a reduction operator, not a bit-wise operator. Reduction operator are described in the *Reduction operators* section all version of the LRM. From Verilog's original IEEE Std 1364-1995 in § 4.1.11 to the latest SystemVerilog [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) in § 11.4.9. Here is an excerpt from [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 11.4.9:

> The *unary reduction operators* shall perform a bit-wise operation on a single operand to produce a single-bit result. For *reduction AND*, *reduction OR*, and *reduction XOR* operators, the first step of the operation shall apply the operator between the first bit of the operand and the second using Table 11-16 through Table 11-18. The second and subsequent steps shall apply the operator between the 1-bit result of the prior step and the next bit of the operand using the same logic table. ...

Bit-wise and reduction operators use the same character (ex: `|`, `&`, `^`). To distinguish the two, check of a value on the left side of the operator. If there is an value, then it is bit-wise, if nothing, then reduction.

You could mix bit-wise and reduction in the same expression. For example `out = &in1 ^ |in2;` where the `&` and `|` are reduction operator (no values on their lefts) and the `^` is bit-wise ( the result of `&in1` is the left value). However, to be more human readable, it is recommenced to make the reduction operations more visually explicit with parenthesizes: `out = (&in1) ^ (|in2);`

Comment: Is there a difference between `wire [3:0] A; assign Y = &A;` and `assign Y = &A[3:0];`? An LLM is insiting there is; that the presence of the part-select in the second case changes the behavior of the `&` from reduction-AND to "suppressing bit expansion". I had not come across this subtle difference before.